# Tune Nested Loop in Scala

Tags: scala

I was wondering if I can tune the following Scala code :

```
def removeDuplicates(listOfTuple: List[(Class1,Class2)]): List[(Class1,Class2)] = {
           var listNoDuplicates: List[(Class1, Class2)] = Nil
           for (outerIndex <- 0 until listOfTuple.size) {
             if (outerIndex != listOfTuple.size - 1)
               for (innerIndex <- outerIndex + 1 until listOfTuple.size) {
                 if (listOfTuple(i)._1.flag.equals(listOfTuple(j)._1.flag))
                   listNoDuplicates = listOfTuple(i) :: listNoDuplicates
               }
           }
           listNoDuplicates
         }
```

Comment: What does *tune* means ?

Comment: I mean to get the shape of functional style . I need to remove the var and use val instead

Comment: OK. Could you also explain what is precisely the expected behavior of the method ?

Comment: I have a list of tuples . I need to remove the duplicates but based on the condition of a flag that existed on both class , i.e. class1 ,Class2

Comment: In case of several tuples with same flag, which one should you keep ?

Comment: Example : val tuple=Tuple((1,2),(3,4),(1,2)) 
   Expected Resule after calling the method : Tuple((1,2),(3,4)) 
   This is just a simple representaion of what I intend to do as I have some class instead of haveing a Tuple(Int,Int)

Comment: Why call `equals`? `==` is the same thing as `equals`.

Comment: Also, what are `i` and `j`? You use it but do not define it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually if you have someting looking like:

```
var accumulator: A = new A
for( b <- collection ) {
    accumulator = update(accumulator, b)
}
val result = accumulator
```

can be converted in something like:

```
val result = collection.foldLeft( new A ){ (acc,b) => update( acc, b ) }
```

So here we can first use a map to force the unicity of flags. Supposing the flag has a type F:

```
val result = listOfTuples.foldLeft( Map[F,(ClassA,ClassB)] ){
            ( map, tuple ) => map + ( tuple._1.flag -> tuple )
          }
```

Then the remaining tuples can be extracted from the map and converted to a list:

```
val uniqList = map.values.toList
```

It will keep the last tuple encoutered, if you want to keep the first one, replace `foldLeft` by `foldRight`, and *invert the argument of the lambda*.

**Example:**

```
case class ClassA( flag: Int )
case class ClassB( value: Int )

val listOfTuples = 
  List( (ClassA(1),ClassB(2)), (ClassA(3),ClassB(4)), (ClassA(1),ClassB(-1)) )

val result = listOfTuples.foldRight( Map[Int,(ClassA,ClassB)]() ) {
  ( tuple, map ) => map + ( tuple._1.flag -> tuple )
}

val uniqList = result.values.toList

//uniqList: List((ClassA(1),ClassB(2)), (ClassA(3),ClassB(4)))
```

**Edit:** If you need to retain the order of the initial list, use instead:

```
val uniqList = listOfTuples.filter( result.values.toSet )
```

Comment: This is amazing approach . I was trying it but as u can see my method takes  List[(Class1,Class2)] . By applying ur approach I couldn't get the expected result !

Comment: @Echo: I've added a compilable example. It works like a charm and the complexity is O(n) thanks to the map.

Comment: Warning: `Map` is not supposed to keep insertion order. Consequently, you do not ensure that the result will be in the same order than the initial list!

Comment: @Nicolas: You are right. I edited the answer to keep the insertion order. Still O(n) I think.

Comment: With your edition, it does not remove strict duplicates anymore if they are strictly equals ex: List(**(1, 2)**, (2, 3), **(1, 2)**). Btw, the complexity depends of the complexity of map insert (O(n)) so... your method is O(n^2)

Comment: The first part is right, if you want to keep the insertion order, you will need something in O(n^2) if you have exact duplicates. However, if order is not important, it's O(n) because standard Map insertion is amortized O(1).

Comment: Thx. I believe I should search more about foldRight to get familiar with its capabilities .Thx Again paradigmatic :)

Answer (score 2):

This compiles, but as I can't test it it's hard to say if it does "The Right Thing" (tm):

```
def removeDuplicates(listOfTuple: List[(Class1,Class2)]): List[(Class1,Class2)] = 
  (for {outerIndex <- 0 until listOfTuple.size
     if outerIndex != listOfTuple.size - 1
     innerIndex <- outerIndex + 1 until listOfTuple.size
     if listOfTuple(i)._1.flag == listOfTuple(j)._1.flag
  } yield listOfTuple(i)).reverse.toList
```

Note that you can use `==` instead of `equals` (use `eq` if you need reference equality).

BTW: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use index with lists (like `listOfTuple(i)`). Index on lists have very lousy performance. So, some ways...

The easiest:

```
def removeDuplicates(listOfTuple: List[(Class1,Class2)]): List[(Class1,Class2)] =
  SortedSet(listOfTuple: _*)(Ordering by (_._1.flag)).toList
```

This will preserve the last element of the list. If you want it to preserve the first element, pass `listOfTuple.reverse` instead. Because of the sorting, performance is, at best, `O(nlogn)`. So, here's a faster way, using a mutable `HashSet`:

```
def removeDuplicates(listOfTuple: List[(Class1,Class2)]): List[(Class1,Class2)] = {
  // Produce a hash map to find the duplicates
  import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
  val seen = HashSet[Flag]()

  // now fold
  listOfTuple.foldLeft(Nil: List[(Class1,Class2)]) {
    case (acc, el) =>
      val result = if (seen(el._1.flag)) acc else el :: acc
      seen += el._1.flag
      result
  }.reverse
}
```

One can avoid using a *mutable* `HashSet` in two ways:

1. Make `seen` a var, so that it can be updated.
2. Pass the set along with the list being created in the fold. The case then becomes:

   ```
   case ((seen, acc), el) =>
   ```

Comment: Thx Daniel for ur assistance .